# read url data specific line java

Tags: java

I need to read lines in URL html page from specific line.

For now, I have the following code:

```
 u = new URL("http://s.ll/message/" + counter);

 is = u.openStream(); // throws an IOException

 dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));

 while ((s = dis.readLine()) != null) {
   if (s.contains('%')
      ...
 }
```

I know that this content will not be before the 50th line.

How can I read just from this line?

And is it the quickest way to read URLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track. To read data from URLs, the simplest way is to just use the URL object. For more complicated HTTP communication tasks you might consider [HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/).

The method you're using *DataInputStream.readLine()* is deprecated since you can't provide the character set used when converting from bytes to string.

I'd do like this:

```
 u = new URL("http://s.ll/message/" + counter);

 is = u.openStream(); // throws an IOException

 // XXX notice the charset set to utf-8 here.
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"));

 while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   if (s.contains('%')
      ...
 }
```

Finding the 50th line requires you to skip to it. Since you can't know at which byte offset into the stream the 50th '\n' (or '\r' or '\r\n' depending on Unix, Mac or Windows line breaks) is - you simply have to count from the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I read just from this line?

Count the lines and ignore the line when the count is below 50. There's no magic way to go straight to line 50 other than just reading the stream and counting the lines. The stream has to be read in anyway.

> And is it the quickest way to read URLs?

Depends. However, a more common approach is [`BufferedReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) + [`InputStreamReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) wherein you specify the charset the webpage is encoded in to avoid [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).